# Arrays in php and input arrays

Tags: php, html, arrays

I wanted to make sure I am adding using these arrays correctly, could someone please go over my code and clarify. I have tried printing the array and nothing is displaying.

HTML

```
Start Date: <input type="text" name="start_date[]"/> 
End Date: <input type="text" name="end_date[]"/> 
Description:<textarea name="position[]"></textarea>
```

PHP

```
initializeArrays(); // Initialize arrays
$_SESSION['start_date_array'][] = $_GET['start_date[]']; // Add html input arrays to a session array.
$_SESSION['end_date_array'][] = $_GET['end_date[]'];
$_SESSION['position_array'][] = $_GET['position[]'];
$_SESSION['submit_employment_message'] = 'Thank you for the submission';
```

I want to set the array I am getting to my session array. Essentially I am expecting there to be multiple start dates. Being submitted to the PHP page. For example there could be multiple of start dates inputted. Please let me know if you need any clarification.
Thank you for the help!

Comment: Did you try to print the output from the php page?  Then you can verify for yourself.

Comment: Yes I tried and it is not printing.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don;t need the brackets in `$_GET['start_date[]'];` just `$_GET['start_date'];` will give you an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
$_SESSION['start_date_array'] = $_GET['start_date'];
$_SESSION['end_date_array'] = $_GET['end_date'];
$_SESSION['position_array'] = $_GET['position'];
```

Form fields that have `[]` appended to their name are assumed to be arrays

Comment: But you know that you don't need them in your example? Because you only have one of each...

Comment: Yeah, there are going to be more, there will be a button where it will add more start dates.

Answer (score 1):

You can make foreach on `$_GET` and retrieve key=value

```
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
    $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
}
```

and retrieve the name of the sessions by the key of `$_GET`